# How can I convert a Firebase Database Snapshot into an Array List in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app using Swift and Firebase. I want to get an array list containing all of the numbers under a certain user id (images attached below). What I mean by this is I want to be able to call a function that returns an array list containing every integer (from low to high) placed as a child of the user id, but not containing their values (in this case "true"). I have already gotten a snapshot of the data (see code below), but I am unsure as to what to do now.

My Code:

```
func likeToLikeForAll() {

    let uid  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("Liked Movies").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print()
            print("SNAP:")
            print(snapshot.value!)
            print()
        }
    })
}
```

The function prints:
[image]

This is an image of the realtime database:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the use case is but  it's best practice to avoid using array's in NoSQL databases like Firebase. There's lots of posts about that here on SO if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array from the keys

```
let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
```